# Using Twisted Deferreds with parallel callbacks, when each is given a different argument

Tags: parameters, twisted, parallel-processing, deferred

I want to create a deferred as follows:

`f1(x1)` and `f2(x2)` are performed in parallel (so to speak)
and after they finish, I run `f3()`
If I had the same parameters, I'd run:

```
d = Deferred()
d.addCallbacks(f1)
d.addCallbacks(f2)
d.addCallback(lambda x: f3())
d.callback(x1)
```

So that I pass `x1` to both `f1` and `f2`. But I need `f1` to get `x1` and so forth.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understood your use case right, but this seems to be something, where a [DeferredList](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto8) would work particularly well.

```
d1 = function_that_returns_a_deferred_1(x1)
d2 = function_that_returns_a_deferred_2(x2)
d = DeferredList([d1, d2])
d.addCallback(lambda ign: f3())
```

This way, f3 will only be executed once both d1 and d2 have completed.